# C++ Xcode OpenCV - No member named in namespace

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

Today I installed the openCV framework for the first time, but I am running in some errors when I call methods of openCV.

I included the following files:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

I've set the search paths like this:

Header search path: /usr/local/include

Library Path: /usr/local/lib

When I try to call cv::putText(...) or cv::line(...) I get the following error:
No member named ... in namespace cv.

I am new to openCV and I don't know if the method names are wrong since the project I have to work on may be referencing an older openCV version.

Comment: In XCode do you have an include path that you can append to?  In makefiles, you just add -I/usr/local/include or in CMake include_directories(/usr/local/include)

Comment: if you're using opencv3, you'll have to `#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>` (all drawing functions were moved there)

Comment: @berak thanx very much!!